# cvc-complex-type.2.3 : Element 'Project' cannot have character children

Tags: xml, spring-boot, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to create a spring boot application, but I get some issue in my project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Java Brains Course API</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

   <properties><java.version> 1.8 </java.version></properties>

</project>
```

I'm getting this error in my pom.xml:

> cvc-complex-type.2.3 : Element 'project' cannot have character [Children], because the type's content type is element-only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the middle of your XML file after the close of `dependencies` element and the start of the `properties` element:

```
</dependencies>

   <properties><java.version> 1.8 </java.version></properties>
```

The BOM is visible in a hex editor as ef bb bf, but invisible as text.  BOMs can only appear at the ***top*** of an XML file, not in the middle.

Here is your XML without the problem:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Java Brains Course API</name>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties><java.version> 1.8 </java.version></properties>
</project>
```

I've also removed unnecessary whitespace for uniformity, but space characters and line breaks between elements are fine and can now be re-introduced per your formatting taste.

Comment: I had a similar error message, and this answer led me to the right answer, so thanks for this. However, I'd like to add that, more generally speaking, the error message means that within the named element ('project' in this case) one or more character appear outside a child element, and that's not valid.